# ¿Cómo se llama palabras como rompecabezas o tapabocas?

Tags: sustantivos, terminología

¿Hay un palabra que quire decir palabras como rompecabezas o tapabocas donde hay un sustantivo compuesto de un verbo y un sustantivo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sustantivos como "rompecabezas" y "tapabocas" son sustantivos compuestos de verbo y nombre (rompe + cabezas / tapa + bocas), o **compuestos verbonominales**, según la terminología que usa la Nueva Gramática de la Lengua Española (punto 11.6.2 del Manual, páginas 200/201).

Otros ejemplos que podemos encontrar en la NGLE son:

- guardacoches
- pintalabios
- rompeolas
- pasatiempo
- quitaesmalte
- guardabarros
- cortafuego
- salvavidas
- portalámpara
- guardarropa
- taparrabo
- quitamanchas